# Magic Software (uniPaaS)- get data from webservice

Tags: web-services, wsdl

Can someone show me a simple example of how to get data from web service on Magic software
.

Assume that I have WSDL file and the function I need called "getData()"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's been awhile since you asked, and hopefully you found an answer by now. But, I have not perused this site before. Anyway, the manual that comes with Magic XPA has a manual, called "Mastering Magic". In Chapter 34 is a step-by-step "how to" for consuming web services.

We (some of the users) also have meetings weekly and you are welcome to join us, to get live walkthroughs for debugging details:

http://unipaasusers.blogspot.com/p/meeting-schedule.html

By and large, web services are very easy in Magic. Being able to automatically define XML files or XML BLOBS as data sources saves a lot of time. The problems tend to occur when there are syntax issues with the XML, which can be "fun"!